# Understanding how to calculate the depth of a Binary Tree

Tags: java, c++, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am going through the Career Cup guide as a crash course through basic CS principals and stuck on the example which calculates the minimum/maximum depth of a Binary Tree. Since this is the same problem I'm having with almost every example I thought I'd post a question here.

The instructions are to implement a method that will check to see if a tree is balanced. In order to do this, you need to compare the minimum depth with the maximum depth, and ensure their difference is no greater than 1. This principal is as straightforward as it gets. The method on line 15 is intended to do just that.

However, I do not understand what is going on in the return statements of each helper method (`maxDepth` and `minDepth`). How is a number being derived from either `root.left` or `root.right`? 
Does the `Math.max` function simply assume a `1` or a `0` is there a value/null node, or, since there is no value being specified (just the `Node` object), does `Math.max(maxDepth(root.left), maxDepth(root.right)` itself equal `0`, thus incrementing the return value by `1` until both nodes are null?

If so is this the general process used to calculate the min/max depth of a tree:

minDepth = does the root have any children? yes = minDepth = 1, no = minDepth = 0 (if there is a root)

maxDepth = cycle through both branches until you find the leaf furthest from the root. Keep a counter going to determine the leaves.

```
1   public static int maxDepth(TreeNode root) {
2       if (root == null) {
3       return 0;
4       }
5       return 1 + Math.max(maxDepth(root.left), maxDepth(root.right));
6   }
7
8   public static int minDepth(TreeNode root) {
9       if (root == null) {
10          return 0;
11      }
12      return 1 + Math.min(minDepth(root.left), minDepth(root.right));
13  }
14
15  public static boolean isBalanced(TreeNode root){
16      return (maxDepth(root) - minDepth(root) <= 1);
17  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`maxDepth(root.left)` returns the max depth of the left sub tree.
`maxDepth(root.right)` returns the max depth of the right sub tree.
The max of these two is the maximal sub tree depth.
Adding 1 for the root node, you get the max depth of the tree.

Suppose this is the tree :

```
            A
         B      C
       D   E   F   G
     H
   I
```

Just by looking at it you can see the max depth is 5 (formed by the path A-B-D-H-I) and the min depth is 3 (formed by several paths, for example A-C-G).

Now, the max depth is 1 (for the root A) + the max depth of the two sub trees.
The first sub tree, whose root is B has max depth 4 (B-D-H-I). The second sub tree, whose root is C has a max depth 2 (C-F).
max(4,2) = 4
Therefore the max depth of the entire tree is 1 + max(4,2) = 5.

If we use the letter in my sample tree to represent the sub-trees rooted in those nodes, we get :

```
maxDepth(A) = 1 + max(maxDepth(B) , maxDepth(C)) =
              1 + max(1 + max(maxDepth(D) , maxDepth(E)), 1 + max(maxDepth(F) , maxDepth(G)) =
              1 + max(1 + max(1+max(maxDepth(H),0) , 1+max(0,0)), 1 + max(1+max(0,0) , 1+max(0,0)) =
              1 + max(1 + max(1+max(1+max(maxDepth(I),0),0) , 1), 1 + 1) =
              1 + max(1 + max(1+max(1+max(1+max(0,0),0),0) , 1), 1 + 1) =
              1 + max(1 + max(1+max(1+max(1,0),0) , 1), 2) =
              1 + max(1 + max(1+max(2,0) , 1), 2) =
              1 + max(1 + max(3 , 1), 2) =
              1 + max(4, 2) =
              1 + 4 =
              5
```

Similarly, for calculating the min depth, you calculate the min depth of the two (left and right) sub-trees, take the minimum of the two, and add 1 for the root.

Comment: That's what I'm not following: how does `maxDepth(root.left)` return the depth of the tree?

Comment: @NealR `maxDepth(root.left)` returns the max depth of the sub tree whose root is the left son of the root of the original tree. If you are not familiar with recursion, it takes time to get used to it (and believe that it actually works).

Comment: Sorry to be thick-headed here, but how are those numbers (max depth) being calculated?

Comment: I'm stuck on how the program increments whatever it uses as the counter

Comment: Traverse all the way down the left side of the tree.  When you get to a leaf node, return the height as 1.  The parent will add 1 to that number. Eventually, your traversal will return to the top with the height of one path of the tree.

Comment: @NealR The counter is the return value of each method call. At the top level, the result is 1 + max (x,y), but x and y are themselves the results of applying this method on a smaller tree.

Comment: Ok. Just to make sure I got this: the recursion stops once x and y are null. At that point the value you've calculated is the maxDepth. That value is determined by: number of times the recusive method was called (equivalent to max number of levels)  + 1 (root node)

Comment: @The recursion stops when `maxDepth` is called for a null TreeNode, which returns 0. Then you return to the previous recursive call of `maxDepth` and calculate its result, and so on, until you return to the first call of `maxDepth`, in which you can finally calculate the maxDepth of the entire tree.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's a recursive function that checks both sides of the tree then compares the result with either max or min.

Pictures help.

```
       o  go left and right
     /    \
(+1)o      o(+1)       
    \       
     o(+1)
```

So lets bring it back to the code.

`return 1 + Math.max(maxDepth(root.left), maxDepth(root.right));`

the call stack would look something like this

```
// max return 2
- left +1                      
    // max return 1
    -left 0                    
    -right +1
       // max return 0
      -left  0                 
      -right 0
- right +1
    //max return 0
    -left 0
    -right 0
```

`Min` works essentially the same way.